# Pgfplots: stacked xbar troubles

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to find a way to present statistical data, specifically percentages that add up to 100. I'm not a fan of pie charts and I've found something I like using stacked xbars.

This is what I have at the moment

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{testbar/.style={
            title=Some title,
            xbar stacked,
            width=10cm,
            axis y line*= none, axis x line*= none,
            xmajorgrids = false,
            xmin=0,xmax=100,
            ytick = data,
            yticklabels = {Some label},
            tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
            bar width=8mm, y=10mm,
            enlarge y limits={abs=0.625},% 0.5 + 0.5*(y - bar width)/y [TeX.sx #47995]
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={left},
            point meta=x,
        }}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[testbar] 
     \addplot[fill=blue!40] coordinates{(46.25,0) };
     \addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}plot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Current output]

As you can see, the label for the second (red) plot is incorrect, I'd like it to be 53.75. The piece of code that changes it is "point meta=x", which I believe marks the ending point of the plot, but this isn't adequate for the second plot. How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help, and I apologize if my question is trivial. This is completely new to me and I wasn't able to find any other questions on the site to resolve these particular details.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (MWE).

Comment: Please ask only a single question in a thread.

Comment: Added MWE, cut it down to one question.

Comment: You can change `point meta=x` to `point meta=rawx` to get the desired value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load `pgfplots` then set immadetly a value for `compat`. If this is missing `pgfplots` uses `compat=pre 1.3` to ensure the compatibility to this really old version.

With at least `compat=1.9` you only have to remove `nodes near coords align={left}, point meta=x` to get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14,% <- current version is 1.14
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{testbar/.style={
        title=Some title,
        xbar stacked,
        width=10cm,
        axis lines*= left,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data,
        yticklabels = {Some label},
        tick align = outside,
        bar width=8mm,
        y=10mm,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.6},% 0.5 + 0.5*(y - bar width)/y [TeX.sx #47995]
        nodes near coords
    }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[testbar] 
 \addplot[fill=blue!40] coordinates{(46.25,0) };
 \addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}plot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really like the old position of the nodes near coords, then change the compatibility settings only for the `bar nodes` to `1.8` using `compat/bar nodes=1.8` and use `nodes near coords align={left},point meta=rawx`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14,% <- added, current version is 1.14
  compat/bar nodes=1.8% <- to use the old settings for bar nodes
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{testbar/.style={
        title=Some title,
        xbar stacked,
        width=10cm,
        axis lines*= left,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data,
        yticklabels = {Some label},
        tick align = outside,
        bar width=8mm,
        y=10mm,
        enlarge y limits={abs=0.6},% 0.5 + 0.5*(y - bar width)/y [TeX.sx #47995]
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={left},
        point meta=rawx
    }}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[testbar] 
 \addplot[fill=blue!40] coordinates{(46.25,0) };
 \addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}plot[fill=red!40] coordinates{(53.75,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```